# Organised backpacking in China (14-Sep till 8-Oct 2012)

Tags: china, tours, backpacking

Wandering the net, I have found this site:

http://thedragontrip.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Detailed%20Itinerary%20-%20HK%20to%20HK%2025%20days.pdf

This fits all my needs:

- comprehensive
- young
- cheap
- English speakers
- 21 +- vacation days
- suits single travelers

However I'm not available at their fixed dates.

Tried to Google it, but found no answer:

1. Are there any other similar backpackers groups in China with the same concept?
2. Are there other places in the world (Asia, Russia) with similar groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a company based in Canada that I first heard about in New Zealand that has tours all over the world - [GAdventures](http://www.gadventures.com/) (formerly GAP Adventures).

In terms of your listed needs, it meets all those, it would seem.

I checked, and they do [indeed have China tours](http://www.gadventures.com/trips/?region=Asia&country=China&duration=%5B16%20TO%2025%5D&q=&ref=finder) of your required duration, as well as tours in many other Asian countries (as well as the rest of the world).

Comment: thanks. have you tried them yourself? heard recommendation?

Comment: I'll stick with TheDragonTrip, as they offer 25 day. I prolonged my vacation. The site you suggested is for backpackers?

Comment: I know of young and old who have travelled with them, and they'd certainly suit backpackers.  My brother travelled with them in South America, and I've got friends who have used them in Africa.